# I can't run my first Android app

Tags: android

I did the following:

I have installed `adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030` and created my first project named `My First App`. But after creating it I am unable to run it in an emulator. There is no AVD available, I tried to create one and launched it,but after that when I tried to run the project by selecting `Run As` under `Run` menu I found the option `none applicable`, instead of which I should have found the option `Run as android App`.

Please let me know where I am going wrong and what exactly I should do.

Comment: You might have the AVD running an older Android version than what is your application's minimum version.

Comment: Check your minSdk version declared in manifest.xml file and your AVD version.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

run configuration-->>choose your project-->>choose 'launch default activity'

move to 'target' tab and select your emulator.

Finally click on apply and run your project

Answer (score 0):

do the following steps:
Project---Clean
then project --build automatically

right click on on your application and select run as it will show you definately run as android application